# Which SPICE circuit Simulator that can show you the circuits equations to be solved for citcuit Analysis?

Tags: spice, ngspice

Which SPICE circuit Simulator that can show you the circuits equations to be solved for citcuit Analysis?

Answer (score 1):

Most SPICE based circuit simulator (to the best of my knowledge), will only provide you operating points and AC/Transient/Noise/etc results assuming your circuit to be a blackbox. You'll not get equations from them.

What you're looking for is a symbolic circuit simulator. I know there are few out there, but the only one I am most familiar with is SLiCAP. You can find it at https://analog-electronics.eu/.

That being said, the expressions derived with any symbolic software can explode pretty quickly if you decide to use complex small-signal models.

Symbolic simulators, like SLiCAP, will happily solve the circuits for you, derive your gain, input-referred noise, AC transfer function, loop gain, etc. However, if you use a high-frequency model for every single of transistor in your simulation, then you're going to end up with huge-*ss expression that will not give you any insight (i.e. high-entropy expressions, quoting Middlebrook).

It is up to you to simplify your circuits such that they are enough to give the insight you're looking for.

Comment: [Here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9044395/) is an interesting coverage on symbolic solvers and I remember using Sapwin successfully in the past. I think TINA which is SPICE-based offers the possibility to obtain symbolic answers.

Comment: @VerbalKint I hope at some point in my life I can find the time to try them all (only the ones based on open-source software though, like SLiCAP is) and see their strengths and weaknesses. I know SLiCAP because I know its creator, and he actually taught me how to use it.